# IP address resolves to an Ubuntu version

Tags: networking, dns

I was looking at logs on a work server (Ubuntu 16.04) and saw `ubuntu-18.04` listed in the host name field.  I checked at home on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, Centos 6, and Windows 10.  They all give the same IP and hostname.  Any idea what gives?

```
Name:    ubuntu-18.04
Address:  159.65.158.229
```

Comment: Clearly the same commands are not used between Linux and windows and there is zero chance they are all on the same public IP. So, please be more specific about what “I was looking at logs..” or “I checked at home...” means. Exact commands/steps used to obtain the information.

Comment: @Appleoddity  "nslookup" on windows 10.  "host" on the Linux boxes.  Work and Home are using different ISPs.  I used different operating systems and ISPs to try and avoid any local misconfiguration or OS bugs.  The printed output was from Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
For some reason, "ubuntu-18.04" is the answer to reverse-DNS queries for that IP address. That's unusual and not best practice, but it's not forbidden by the protocol either.

**Long answer:**
ARIN, the American Registry for Internet Numbers, assigned IPv4 net block 159.65.0.0/16 to a company called Digital Ocean. Thus, Digital Ocean's authoritative name servers get to answer all inverse (reverse) DNS requests asking for the hostnames associated with IPv4 addresses in that range.

When you send an inverse-DNS request to Digital Ocean's authoritative name servers to ask what hostname is associated with 169.65.158.229, Digital Ocean's DNS servers respond with the string "ubuntu-18.04". This is not forbidden by the DNS protocol, but it is not considered a best practice. The best practice would be to return a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for that host, and for that FQDN to have an "A" (address) record pointing back at that IPv4 address. But for some reason, maybe by mistake, Digital Ocean's servers aren't returning an FQDN for that query. They're just returning the string "ubuntu-18.04".